# Why is my algorithm in an infinite print loop?

Tags: c++, loops, graphic

I'm trying to make a code which simulates the functionality of a graphic editor. The user has to type an instruction, which is a character, followed by the parameters that each action will have.

The maximum size of the image is 250, so I created a vector of 250 chars on the top of the scope.
My strategy was to, in the case of coloring a pixel, I could just chose the coordinates of this vector and the color I wanted (which is also represented as a char) and assign them equally.

At first, the code seems ok. But when I type 'L' for the coloring pixel function, it just goes to an infinite loop, printing the matrix over and over again. Which is actually pretty weird, considering this function doesn't even have a loop.

Where did I miss?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int res;

char imagem[250][250];
char comando;
int m, n;
int i, j;
int x, y;
char cor;


void createImage() {
    cin >> m >> n;
    for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++){
            imagem[i][j] = 'o';
        }
    }
}

void cleanImage(){
    for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
            imagem[i][j] = 'o';
        }
    }
}

void printImage() {
    for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
            printf("%c", imagem[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void paintPixel() {
    cin >> x >> y >> cor;
    imagem[x][y] = cor;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    while (comando != 'X') {
        cin >> comando;
        switch(comando) {
            case 'I': createImage();
            case 'C': cleanImage();
            case 'J': printImage();
            case 'L': paintPixel();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about break; statement in the end of each case?

Comment: Leaving char "imagem[250][250];" aside, the rest of the globals are a no no, for sure.

Comment: @Valek, they're static storage duration hence will be initialised to zero.  There's no UB involved there.

Comment: What about an `cin.clear()` after the `switch`-statement?

Comment: For completeness, you should actually tell us your input stream. In other words, what _exactly_ are you entering into this program?

Comment: I've put cin.clear() after the switch and it stopped looping! The only problem is that the paintPixel() function won't work. I mean, the char doesn't change in the matrix. My input is exactly "I 3 3" (creating matrix) "L 2 2 R" (changing char name from location [2][2] of my matrix) "J" (printing the result). Any guess?